# JS-to-PHP ajax request not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

$_POST is not being filled after the use of XMLHttpRequest in JS.

HTML + JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>T</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="press">Sample button</button>
    </body>
    <script>
        document.querySelector('#press').addEventListener('click', function() {
            var js = JSON.stringify({
                name: "String"
            });

            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open('POST', 'P.php/');
            req.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
            req.send(js);
            
            req.onload = function() {
                alert(req.response);
            }

        });
    </script>
</html>
```

PHP is just an " echo $_POST["name"] "; it results in an error (Undefined array key "name"), im expecting to get "String" in req.response

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php

Comment: thanks bro. `$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);` worked for me